# Need expert advice on use of SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server

I have an application, with SQL Server Express Database.

I made an instance of SQL Server Express and connected it with a basic report for testing.

On the development server, it works ok.

Then I shared the folder and then ran the application from some other network computer (LAN)
It gave error that it could not find the server.

1. Could you advise what could be the problem.
2. Also when this application is installed on another computer, how does my dataconnection adjust itself.  The current dataconnection is based in the server instance of SQL Server installed on my development computer.
3. How does my application automatically create new server instance on any of client's computer and connects to it?  Like Inflow creates InflowSQL instance wherever it is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure a couple of things:

1. The SQL Server Browser service is started (by default, SQL Server Express is a named instaned)
2. The protocol TCP/IP is enabled (by default, it is disabled)

You can do this all through the SQL Server Configuration Manager (run "sqlservermanager10.msc" if you're using SQL Server 2008 [R2 optional]).

Comment: Thanks !  So when I make a setup file, and install on client's computer, does my connection string adjust automatically?  I am running SQL Server Express 2005

Comment: @FurqanSehgal Unless you are using the `data source` as "localhost", "(local)", or ".", then you will be able to port a connectionstring anywhere within the network.

Comment: So I just make a setup and my clients install it.  My connection string shall work like [Data Directory] works?

Comment: @FurqanSehgal if you are installing the database on a local instance every time, you can just use `localhost` and it'll point to the loopback (127.0.0.1) every time.  If that is your desired effect, which it sounds like it is, then yes that connection string will remain the same.

Comment: and if I use this localhost in connection string, this will not have problem in running the application over network, in sharing environment?

Comment: @FurqanSehgal Where is your SQL Server Express instance going to reside?  On each workstation, or a central location (i.e. server or dedicated machine)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6620/discussion-between-furqan-sehgal-and-shark)